# In PSPICE how do I get a plot showing the reflection co efficient on the y axis?

Tags: pspice, reflection

I need to plot a graph of the reflection coefficient against the frequency.I ran an AC sweep of in the range of frequencies I need. However I am unsure of how to get the reflection coefficient on the y axis for the circuit I want to stimulate. Will I have to use an additional component ?. Anybody familar with PSPICE please advice?.

Comment: does anyine have any idea about this please

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a means to measure input voltage and input current from your circuit.  Then you can convert to complex impedance: Zl = V/I

Then gamma = (Zl - Zo) /(Zl + Zo) where Zo is the transmission line impedance.

You may be able to use an AC current source Into the DUT to find impedance